# Retrieving layouts from managed package in package.xml

Tags: managed-package, package.xml

I have tried the following way in `package.xml`

```
<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>abc__ObjectA__c-ObjectA Layout</members>
        <members>abc__ObjectB__c-ObjectB Layout</members>
        <members>xyz__ObjectX__c-ObjectX</members>                
        <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

But I am not able to retrieve the layouts, can someone please help me where it is going wrong.

Comment: Do you get an error? Saying *I am not able to do X* is rather vague and rarely gets good answers. Saying instead *I get this error message: ...* will make it much easier to assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case if you want to retrieve layout from managed package, you need to specify package prefix as well.

Below you will find 2 examples, first one is *managed* layout for managed object, and second one is *unmanaged* (custom) layout for managed object, abc__ is namespace prefix, :

```
<types>
    <members>abc__object__c-abc__object Layout</members>
    <members>abc__object__c-custom name Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

Please, ensure that you have entered layout name properly, it is case sensitive in package.xml.

Comment: Thanks, this info was hard to find. For the record, another possibility is if you're looking for a packaged layout for a standard object, its Object-abc__Object layout